# Difference between .NET 4 and .NET 4.8

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.8

I have project created in .NET 3.5 or 4 and wanted to migrate it on .NET 4.8. What is key difference between them? Also what parameter I should take care while migrating an application? I still don't have the source code but meanwhile what kind of measure I should take care?

Comment: .NET 3.5 is a completely different runtime from 4.0. Migration from 3.5 to 4.0 can be tricky. There's no 4.0 in *any* supported Windows OS. All .NET Framework 4.x runtimes are binary replacements which means installing a fresh version eg throutg Windows Update replaces the older one. This means your application is already being developed and deployed on 4.5.2 at least

Comment: As for ASP.NET , things are *completely* different between ASP.NET 2.0 and the current versions. By now WebForms are essentially abandoned. WCF isn't popular because SOAP services are no longer popular, they were replaced by REST services. The ASP.NET MVC stack nowadays is very different from the first couple of versions that worked on .NET Framework 4.

Comment: `I still don't have the source code but meanwhile what kind of measure I should take care?` The platform itself is different. This is more a rewrite than a migration. Web standards and expectations have changed. Start with the Getting Started and Tutorials sections at docs.microsoft.com and look for courses. You can get a few months of free access to Pluralsight's courses though the (also free) Visual Studio Essentials program. You *do* need to know if it's WebForms or MVC, simply to know what tutorials and courses to search for. I'd bet it's WebForms, otherwise they wouldn't be stack at 4.0

Comment: What features are you using? What research have you done on the differences for those features? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: If you don't have the source code, then this becomes a not at all the best idea. .net runtimes as a general rule can consume the older .net .dll's and assemblies, but quite much the whole idea in a framework upgrade is the assuming that you going to re-compile your code. Having source code is thus quite much a basic requirement here, kind of like fish needing water to swim in. I think your LARGER issue is not having source code, and then expecting to upgrade a frame work - VERY bad idea.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/ There is a whole lot of documentation available for you to digest, but to be realistic you have to hire an expert to take a look

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to read [.Net Framework 4.8 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-net-framework-4-8/).

after that read about [migrating projects to .Net Framework 4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/) and pay attention to the migration resource section.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without the source code, then you can update the framework all you want, the compiled code is still going to point to, and use the older framework. So, without source code this idea is a non starter.

I have found that in most cases, the code will compile. But then again, you need the source code to compile.

So, upgrade from say 3.5 to 4.0, or 4.8? Useally VERY issue - and often zero code changes are reuqired. But then again, you would compile the code to find out if there is a issue or error in the code - and you would thus know in less then 10 seconds of your time.

But, messing around with the framework, and you don't have the original source code project and the ability to re-build that project from VS?

No, this idea makes ZERO sense without the original project and YOUR ability to re-build the project.

Since you don't have source code, then upgrading frame work not really going to help much, since existing compiled code will continue to point to the older framework anyway, and thus you not really upgrading anything at all, are you?

With souce code, the risk here is rather small. I betting that the project would compile and run by changing the project to .net 4.0, or better yet, 4.8.

you will certainly have to ensure that the web host and server has .net 4.8 installed on that server.

However, you need to be able to re-build that project from source code for this to be a workable up-grade.